# Can't give myself NOPASSWD privelege for chmod/chown

Tags: permissions, sudo

I'm trying to set my local computer (which has Linux Mint 13 Maya) so that I can `chmod` & `chown`  any file with my regular `max` user account.

Following this page, 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

I've done the following:

```
#edit the /etc/sudoers file via `visudo` 
sudo visudo

#in the file, added these lines:
Cmnd_Alias NOPASS_CMNDS = /bin/chmod, /bin/chown
max ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: NOPASS_CMNDS
```

Then saved. (I got the locations for chmod and chown using `which`)

So, my `visudo` file now looks like this:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Cmnd_Alias NOPASS_CMNDS = /bin/chmod, /bin/chown
max ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: NOPASS_CMNDS

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

This is the output from `sudo -l`

```
$ sudo -l
Matching 'Defaults' entries for max on this host:
    env_reset, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User max may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod, /bin/chown
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

I then open a new shell tab and try to `sudo chmod` a file which is owned by a different user & group, and it asks me for a password:

```
$ ls -l  tmp/0000000001
-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 19245781 Sep 10 16:59 tmp/0000000001

$ sudo chmod +w tmp/0000000001
[sudo] password for max:
```

Am I missing something here?  I don't know if I've done it wrong or have misunderstood what I was actually trying to change.

Do I need to reboot, or reload/restart something to see the change?

Comment: And when you do post there, remember to add the output of `sudo -l` and the lines in `sudoers` which come after the lines you added.

Comment: Did you save _and exit_ `visudo` or just save?

Comment: Save and exit (`esc` then `:wq`)

Comment: That's very odd. I just tried this on my LMDE (Linux Mint Debian) and it worked as expected.

Comment: I've added (to my question) the content of my `visudo` file and the output from `sudo -l` - can you see anything there which might be breaking it?

Comment: What's the output of `type -a chmod`?

Comment: `chmod is /bin/chmod`

Comment: That's really weird.  Look, it really shouldn't be necessary, changes to `sudoers` take effect as soon as `visudo` is closed but you may as well reboot if possible, just to make sure there's nothing keeping `visudo` open  somewhere.

Comment: What happens if you type the full path, i.e. `sudo /bin/chmod +w tmp/0000000001`?

Comment: @JennyD it still asks for my password.

Comment: Is `max` a member of the `admin` or `sudo` groups? (I think this is the case because `(ALL : ALL) ALL` appears in your `sudo -l` output). The config line for that group may be taking precedence over the NOPASSWD line.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick When I tried adding my testuser to wheel in my test server, I got the same issue. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: The solution is to post the lines with NOPASSWD lower down in the config than the line granting ALL to the admin/wheel/sudo group.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yes it is - `$ groups max` gives `max : max root adm cdrom sudo audio dip www-data plugdev fuse lpadmin netdev powerdev sambashare`, showing that `max` is in the `sudo` group.  Would you mind doing an answer with a suggested fix?

Comment: @JennyD - that's fixed it, thanks!  If you want to make that an answer i will mark it correct.

Comment: It was @MarkPlotnick that found it... although I found how to solve it, so I'll write it up :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that there are two rules for this user:

```
(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod, /bin/chown
(ALL : ALL) ALL
```

The second one comes from the line in sudoers reading

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Sudo will use the first matching rule starting from the bottom of the file - so when you need to have different options for a subset of commands, you need to make sure that they are listed **below** the more generic line.

In other words, you need to make sure that the line

```
max ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: NOPASS_CMNDS
```

is placed **after** the line

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

in the file.