# Restart OpenVPN Service Without a Password

Tags: openvpn, systemctl

Can someone tell me how to run this without a password prompt:

```
systemctl restart openvpn@myvpn.service`
```

in my sudoers file I have:

```
<myadminuser> ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl openvpn@myvpn.service restart,/etc/init.d/openvpn
```

and in ~/.bashrc I have:

```
alias or="systemctl restart openvpn@myvpn.service"
```

**Solutions that I have tried:**

If I add "sudo" in the alias, a password is requested inside the terminal.  If I don't add sudo in the alias, box pops up, requesting a password.  Hence, I posted the question here.

Comment: You aren't actually using `sudo`.

Comment: when I add sudo to the alias requests a password inside terminal... when I remove sudo from the alias.... it pops up a windows and asks for a password... hence, reason I asked the question..  loosing two points for asking a question sucks.

Comment: @yupthatguy missing that information out of your question is most likely to be the reason the question got down-voted.  You can [edit] your question to show what you tried, and state why it didn't work (what it did that you didn't want it to).  I would edit it for you, but I don't quite understand what you say you tried.

Comment: In that case, run `sudo -l` to see if some other rule is overriding it (e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230318/70524)

Comment: Huh, your `sudoers` rule is `systemctl openvpn@myvpn.service restart`, and you're running `systemctl restart openvpn@myvpn.service`.

Comment: @muru, I am obviously new to this.. I am simply trying to find a way to reset my openvpn after a dropped connection without a password... not trying to win any computing awards. If you know a better way please share it. thx

Comment: Irrespective of all that, you could see that those two have `restart` in different places.

Comment: ok.. after googling for a while I found a similar command to restart apache2, hoped that I could convert it for openvpn.. didn't work... guess I need a BA in comp science before I post a simple question

Comment: I ran sudo -l there is no other command overruling the openvpn command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sudoers` file you have an incorrect entry, so it's never matched. It should be this (notice the position of the `restart` action compared to your original),

```
<myadminuser> ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl restart openvpn@myvpn.service,/etc/init.d/openvpn
```

Then in your alias you need to use `sudo`,

```
alias or="sudo systemctl restart openvpn@myvpn.service"
```

---

As a related thought, you may be able to avoid the need to do any of this by using the OpenVPN keep-alive option, which you add to your client configuration

```
keepalive 10 60
```

This tells the OpenVPN client to send a "hello" message every 10 seconds (it's not an ICMP `ping` despite the usual description of these values), and if no reply has been received within 60 seconds restart the connection. If necessary you could experiment with reducing this to, say, a 40 second timeout but I wouldn't go lower than that.

Comment: Thanks for just answering the question, rather than questioning my basic intelligence.

Comment: You may also want to look at the keep-alive options, which will do this sort of thing for you automatically. I'll see if I can dig out a suitable set of options

Comment: Thx for the tip... I actually have that in my config, but I guess my vpn service is crappy because ever so often, it just won't reconnect.  So I'd rather restart openvpn, rather than reboot.  thx again.